# Looking for replacement transistor for Branson B52 ultrasonic cleaner

Tags: transistors, replacement

I’m trying to repair a Branson B52 ultrasonic cleaner which has two bad transistors since the wires broke off the transducers.

[image]

[image]

I fixed that up, and noticed when running (barely and would fail the foil test), that a resistor overheated.

[image]

I further tested all the resistors (including the burnt one), diodes and transistors and came to the conclusion that two of the transistors are toast from some voltage drop testing between pins.
(Red circled ones)

[image]

[image]

I can’t find any info on the transistors. Any help would be awesome.

I’m considering switching to an [HD1750FX](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/hd1750fx.pdf) for all transistors despite the package change as legit T-03s are unobtainium now. A confirmation that this is a suitable replace would be great, I’m not experienced in this area of electronics.

Comment: The markings on those transistors isn't quite readable. What's written on them exactly?

Comment: Can you verify that the transistor marking is 
SCS 458-056.  It also seems that you may have some corrosion in the lower right of the PCB, (as seen in the top side picture).

Comment: _"I fixed that up"_ - Exactly how did you 'fix that up'? Have you tested the transidtors out of circuit?

Comment: @Nedd SCS 458-056 , Italy 505. That board pictured isn’t mine, just that my specific one wasn’t accessible at the time of post. I will update the post

Comment: @BruceAbbott I clipped back the crispy wire, and resoldered in place with a high heat soldering gun. The transistors weren’t tested out of circuit, but rather in circuit. I will circle the ones that I’m pretty sure had gone bad

Comment: According to [this page](https://vetco.net/products/nte53-npn-transistor-high-speed-switch) the NTE53 is a direct equivalent. It has a link to the datasheet so you can compare with your replacement choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ST 458-056 T0-3 parts available on ebay:
(Note that STMicro resulted from a merger between Thomas Semi and SGS in 1987)
[ST 458-056](https://www.ebay.com/itm/275210360356?hash=item4013d0d624:g:QT4AAOSwxdZiLkVP&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsDLg0y8QYtfWN4%2BJE88kmZowXgbKkdkJIxNrDjx4OtTo0yiadISG17jReae9b8BQ%2B1Kjum3bMZ%2FZaEmUcuJk%2BRhvpbWIiblk5kk4leG4Uebz2E1xj5U0nBRb3OFwycuvPaFm6w21VJH7MYpqMkesC9MvIgu90WxxTHZlCKuFEReqC8iZwe9lsy6tXDT5KsB9M9TeLyfUN4LCA0azMKeLsI68VzHT6u26Mmr3O3XN0MXv%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR4Dy1NaTYQ)

On another site there are a few original SGS 458-056 and ST 458-056 parts:
[SCS458-056](https://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/SCS%20PRODUCTS/SCS%20PRODUCTS/458-056/)
[ST458-056](https://www.radwell.com/Buy/ST%20MICRO/ST%20MICRO/458-056)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the HD1750FX is also suitable instead of the [original](https://alhekmh.com/458-056-transistor-npn-850v-15a-to-3/) 850 V (VCEV) and 15 A NPN transistor. Its direct [replacement](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/NTE53/11648168) would be the NTE53.

Comment: Even more important:
It looks like the original TO-3 transistors were electrically insulated from the heat sink and the mounting screws connected the transistor body to the PCB trace. If using the same heat sink and the power tab parts be sure the heat sink remains insulated from the PCB trace regardless of how you mount the new parts. If there are plastic insulators under the original parts you might reuse them to keep the mounting hardware insulated from the heat sink. The HD1750FX part says it has a fully insulated package so you may not even need an electrical insulator under it.

Comment: If you use one of the replacement power tab parts you will need to determine the original original transistor pin out connections going to the PCB then hand wire the corresponding power tab pins to the same points on the board.